# Why are Node js environment variables written in all caps and underscores?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

From http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables, "... getting and setting of environment variables is via process.env. By convention, environement variables are in all caps, with words separated by underscores, LIKE_THIS."

And https://codeburst.io/how-to-easily-set-up-node-environment-variables-in-your-js-application-d06740f9b9bd: "You can use whatever names you’d like, but the general naming convention is all-caps with underscores between words."

Why? Is there any legitimate argument against using camel case?

Comment: You quoted it yourself: *"By convention"* .

Comment: Because Unix convention is that environment variables are named iwht ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERSCORES. This is called *constant case* in some circles since many people name program constants using this style.

Comment: Why do you call them "node.js environment variables"? They are just environment variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, these are not *environment variables*, but *environment constants* in the scope of your app.
It's a convention to name constants in capital letters.

The underscore just makes it more readable.

You can still use camelCase if you prefer, it's a matter of choice.