# FirebaseError: Failed to load environment variables from .env

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am using Firebase to run the backend for my application. When I try to run the backend using
`firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions` it says

Node v: 18.13.0
Firebase-tools v: ^11.18.0
Firebase-functions v: ^4.2.0

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, storage
⚠  functions: You are running the Functions emulator in debug mode (port=9229). This means that functions will execute in sequence rather than in parallel.
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: firestore, database, hosting, pubsub
⚠  functions: Unable to fetch project Admin SDK configuration, Admin SDK behavior in Cloud Functions emulator may be incorrect.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/home/ktk/code/js/sol/functions/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load environment variables from .env.
```

Things I've checked:

- the .env does exist
- the .env syntax is correct
- executed `chmod 777 .env` to change the permissions

Comment: there may be an issue with permissions - ensure the .env file is writable.

Comment: I did `chmod 777 .env` and still the error persists

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76037979/firebaseerror-error-provided-secretkey-is-invalid it looks like you resolved this issue. What was the fix?

Answer (score 10):

The problem here could be that you are using reserved firebase names for your environment variable keys.You can take a look to the [Firebase Config Env](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?hl=es-419#reserved-names) documentation.

Any key that starts with the word FIREBASE is reserved.

I had the same problem, and I could solve it by changing the name of my env variables.

I hope that helps. Good luck! :)

Comment: Ivan is correct. My error said **Error:** `Failed to load environment variables from .env.:` but what I failed to do was look below it where it also said `Error Key FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL starts with a reserved prefix (X_GOOGLE_ FIREBASE_ EXT_)` along with several other keys that I used. I simply changed the prefix to `MYFIRE_DATABASE_URL` and made the same update in the my `index.js` file as in `admin.initializeApp({ ... databaseURL: process.env.MYFIRE_DATABASE_URL,...` and everything worked. Thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing here, as I was getting the same error. Another cause of this terrible unreadable error message is having any env keys that are not in `UPPERCASE=""`.

For example, a key like this: `APP_projectId_API_KEY="foo"` will cause this error.

Dotenv files aren't meant to have this restriction. By convention, app/environment *constants* are written in uppercase, but this should be a choice - see:  [Why are Node js environment variables written in all caps and underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747839/why-are-node-js-environment-variables-written-in-all-caps-and-underscores)

Answer (score 2):

I was using the "PORT" key in my `.env` file. This key is in the list of [reserved Firebase keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#reserved-names).

Really wish the error message was more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables . env, do not use reserved environment variables that use Firebase.
List of reserved environment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#reserved-names

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

This may happen for any reason:

Double-check that the file contains lines like:

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=XYZ123 
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=mydomain.firebaseapp.com 
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com 
etc...
```

Check that the .env file is indexed in your `gitignore` or `.npmignore`. Environment variables will not be loaded if the file is ignored.
And ensure there are no spaces around the = when setting the variables.

Comment: I have checked everything you said, i do not have a .npmignore. and I removed the env form the gitignore as well. It also doesnt have spaces but still the error persists

Comment: The error message indicates that there's a problem with loading environment variables from the .env file. you have to be sure `.env` file exists at the root get console.log for this, or if this is possible as your error log shows update the package or even restart simuloator

Comment: Pleases revise this answer - any keys starting with `FIREBASE_` will cause an error.